# How to optimize the pdf files using itextsharp or any other third party library

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a window application in C#.I have to optimize the pdf files for ipad use.The files will vary from 20 to 100 MB in size.
and i want the optimized files' size less than 10 mb.

I have used itextsharp and pdftron but it did not fulfill my requirement.Can you please suggest any other way which reduce the size according to my need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly do you want to optimise it? Just clip and scale images to the right resolution, or rebuild font subsets, or vector overlaps processing, or something else?

Comment: Can you please suggest me any help documentation or any appropriate tool for the above purpose?Should i write my own algorithm for achieving the high optimization?

Answer (score 1):

How about using Docotic? It's not free, but I think it would get you where you wanted to go very quickly and this may pay for itself very quickly anyway ($600 for unlimited users):

http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/help/compress-existing-pdf-document.aspx

You also may be able to get away with buying just the Viewer Edition, which is only $250'ish:

http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/purchase.aspx#viewer-edition

Comment: Thanks for your kind help,but the client is not ready to pay such a big amount.is there any way?

Comment: Sure, duly noted and I thought as much... It just usually happens in my experience with just about anything excel that by the time I develop a solution, work out the kinks, work out browser compatibility issues, test and/or unit test the wheel that I reinvented, and deal with any issues different versions of excel, the tool would have long paid for itself.  That said, I don't know a FOSS product that would do what you're asking, and I am curious to see if anyone else does find a FOSS excel compressor.